# Windows phone 8 design - logo in detailed pages

Tags: mobile, metro, windows-phone-7, native-app

Is it good to have logo in detailed pages of an app?

For example Page 1 contains list of posts, on clicking it we go to detailed view of each post → Page 2.

On clicking comments on Page 2 you go to comments page → PAGE 3.

In such a hierarchy of design, Is it advisable to have logo on top left (it's about 100 px) on Page 2 and Page 3 according to windows phone design language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to perform some action, like taking user back to the page 1, then yes.

But I think you're keeping it just as a semi-transparent logo which does nothing. And I'd hate that. It would look like you're trying to advertise something and everyone hates advertisements.

Comment: No Im not performing any action on click of logo..

Answer (score 1):

This is more a matter of style. I prefer to keep logo off the detail pages and keep it only on the main page and splash screens/tiles.

What you do want is to keep the branding *feel* throughout the application. You can do that by carefully choosing colors and fonts.

If you are really keen on placing the logo on detail pages, you can put it either in the top right besides the text that already tells what that page is about, or you could replace the so called "application title" text you get when you create a new page in the Visual Studio.